# "Differentiation in the direction of $X$" defines a Lie algebra representation

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a real Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$.  We have the $\mathbb R$-algebra $\mathscr C^{\infty}(G)$ of smooth functions $G \rightarrow \mathbb R$.  I have heard that $X \mapsto dX$ defines a Lie algebra homomorphism $\mathfrak g \rightarrow \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb R} \mathscr C^{\infty}(G)$, i.e. a representation of $\mathfrak g$.

Here $dX$ is defined to be "differentiation in the direction $X$."  What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would like to mimic the usual derivative (of functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$) that is $$\lim_{t\to 0}{f(x+t)-f(x)\over t}$$

Since the output of $f$ is still a real number in the present case ($f:G\to \Bbb R$), the process of subtracting values of $f$ and dividing them by some $t\neq 0$ still makes sense. What doesn't make sense yet is $x+t$. You can't add an element of $G$ with a real number.

Part of the reason is that a Lie group may have a dimension greater than $1$, meaning that the variable has more freedom than a single real number can encode. Therefore, we are going to use the idea of [*directional derivatives*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) from the context of multivariable calculus. A *direction*, in our Lie context, is an element of the Lie algebra, thought of as the tangent space to the Lie group.

Finally, given a vector $X\in \mathfrak{g}$ and a real number $t$, we need a way to move some $g\in G$ along $tX$. How does one move an element of the group in a direction indicated by an element of the algebra? This is exactly what the [*exponential map*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory)) does.

Therefore, assume given $f\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(G)$. Then $d_Xf\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(G)$ is defined by $$d_Xf(g)=\lim_{t\to 0}{f(g\cdot exp(tX))-f(g)\over t}$$

More info in [these notes](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwjxwY6gw_zaAhXBxRQKHSEdB_wQFghbMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9780817649432-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1261040-p174191758&usg=AOvVaw2SrwRtt8qTEiMj6h-XGYzg). You can also have a look at the [Wikipedia on Lie derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative) - in particular, the introduction contains the equation that lies behind the phrasing "Lie algebra homomorphism".